# How to set height of cell inside tableview cell when set label text multiline at run time

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, xcode9.4

[image]I have got an address from latitude and longitude using reverse Geocoding and set in a label. But the text is not getting multiline. Because cell height is not increased at runtime I used table view cell custom class and set data in table view inside cell custom class and I used below function to get an address and send parameter **pdblLatitude** and **pdblLongitude** inside **cellForRowAt** function

```
 func getAdressName(pdblLatitude: String, withLongitude pdblLongitude: String)
        {
            var center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
            let lat: Double = Double("\(pdblLatitude)")!
            //21.228124
            let lon: Double = Double("\(pdblLongitude)")!
            //72.833770
            let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
            center.latitude = lat
            center.longitude = lon

            let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)
            ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc) { (placemarks, error) in
                if error != nil {

                    print("Hay un error")

                } else {
                    var addressString : String = ""
                    let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

                    if pm.count > 0 {
                        let pm = placemarks![0]


                        if pm.subLocality != nil {
                            addressString = addressString + pm.subLocality! + " "
                        }
                        if pm.locality != nil {
                            addressString = addressString + pm.locality! + " "
                        }
                        if pm.country != nil {
                            addressString = addressString + pm.country! + " "
                        }

                        print("addressString\(addressString)")
                        self.lbladdress.text = addressString
                        self.lbladdress.numberOfLines = 0
                        self.lbladdress.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
                         LoadingView.shared.dismiss()
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Had you used constraints for table view cell for the label? If yes then there is some issue with constraints please check them first.

Comment: Second thing you need to reload the specific cell after setting the text in the label as the method is async call and it will call and set the text in label after the table is loaded

Comment: Have you checked: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells ?

Comment: @ The iOSDev, I have set data in a cell inside the cell class

Comment: try set self.lbladdress.text = addressString in main thread and self.lbladdress.superview.layoutifneed()

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done all required stuff.

Please ensure your lable height is greater then required height.

Please modified your label frame as below, then it will be automatically multiline.

```
self.lbladdress.frame = Set Label frame as per your text
```